What's the best remote access option without port forwarding?
Ubuntu 20.04.
Company does not allow port forwarding. I'm currently using TeamViewer but it's very unreliable. I don't mind a CLI or desktop, just need something reliable.

What's unreliable about TeamViewer? If port forwarding really isn't an option, AnyDesk / Supremo

Have you tried RealVNC?
